# I'm not able to animate my ng-show/ng-hide animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I know this is a well known problem and has been asked multiple times in this forum, but I have not found good answers.

```js
var aniApp = angular.module("aniApp", []);

aniApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.currentStep = 1;

    $scope.show = function(step) {
      $scope.currentStep = step;
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
.step-box {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  padding: 20px;
}
.animate-show {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  padding: 20px;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove,
.animate-show.ng-hide-add {
  display: block!important;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-add {
  animation: 1s flyOut;
}
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
  animation: 1s flyIn;
}
@keyframes flyIn {
  from {
    left: 600px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes flyOut {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -600px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="aniApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div ng-show="currentStep === 1" class="step-box animate-show">
      showing step 1
    </div>
    <div ng-show="currentStep === 2" class="step-box animate-show">
      showing step 2
    </div>
    <div ng-show="currentStep === 3" class="step-box animate-show">
      showing step 3
    </div>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="show(1)">One</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" ng-click="show(2)">Two</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#" ng-click="show(3)">Three</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/q11n9F?p=preview

Inside the box I want the text to come in from the right and get out on the left. This should be easy but I have used the whole day :-(

Can anyone see why this does not work?

Comment: check angular ngShow example, there is plunker script a s well. adapt under your requirements https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#

Comment: Based on the example in the docs this should work:

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0QcanY?p=preview

Comment: My last changes, and I'm almost there..... http://plnkr.co/edit/4SJZzo?p=preview

Comment: I forked your plunker and achieved what I assume is the effect you expect, you can check it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0B6okDk0B5Nclhps3off?p=preview... If you click too fast there will be some undesirable animation, this could be easily solved by disabling the buttons during the animation. Check my comments in the css file, hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the script tag with the angular ng-animate module, since it is not part of the angular core, and you must inject angular ng-animate module as a dependency of your app.

In your html:

```
//After angular.min script tag
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

In your js:

```
  var aniApp = angular.module("aniApp", ['ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: Sorry, that line was missing by mistake. Adding the angular-animate-reference and modifing my javascript does not change any thing. I'm wonder if it has to do with my css-classes? I'll do some more research but it's hard to find a working example that tells me which classes to use to give the effect I want.